# Weird C code (20-30 years old)

Tags: c

So I am in charge of attempting to rebuild a tool, it's a massive test suite for IPDS(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Intelligent_Printer_Data_Stream_%28IPDS%29) and it has all kinds of weirdness in it. For example, this comes from a .c file and there are a bunch more with this syntax. This TEST function that doesn't have the normal syntax you would expect. Yes this compiles somewhere...

```
#include "stdbase.h"

TEST( tbuf, cbasedev, 1.0, test, IUO, 001)
  {
  buffer buf;
  Message (INFORMATION, INFORMATION, "Value of NULL is %d\n", NULL);
  buf = AllocBuf(16384);
  ListBuf();
  }
ENDTEST
```

Do any of the masters understand the syntax in this? The ENDTEST makes me think of #ifndefine/#define/#endif statements, so perhaps it was before the time of that syntax.

Even better, this C code was built off of an original solution programmed in FORTRAN 77. Even better, they have files dedicated to generating/tracking literally dozens of global variables. Oh joy.

That #include "stdbase.h" is a files that just has a ton of other #include "*_*.h"s.

Are there any programs out there for really ancient code where you point it at the top directory and it tries to move through and figure out what relies on what, and what uses what? Like a UML diagram generator almost.

Comment: that's K&R C. it looks completely fine

Comment: C used to implicitly return `int` when the type was omitted.

Comment: gcc -M shows all of the header dependancies

Comment: @Steve, oh wow, then it is ancient. I can't even find the file with the main function.

Comment: why don't you just run the file through the preprocessor to see what those macros expand to?

Comment: no, you cant define a function with literals in the definition. what is that

Comment: @SteveCox oh yeah that is weird I retract my previous statement...

Comment: @Grady: I am used to ANSI C so, not seeing prototypes, at least so far and return values would bother anyone who has never seen K&R C.

Comment: The problem with this snippet isn't the lack of an explicit return type, as `int` used to be the implicit return type (and type of function arguments), the problem is the missing `return [retval]`. If this was a function, and implicitly returned an `int`, it wouldn't know which. I'd say it's a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdbase.h` is not a standard C library header.  It must be something specific to the product you're working on.  From the looks of it, TEST/ENDTEST look like unit tests--are you using a unit test framework?  There was nothing "before" #define--the K&R C preprocessor didn't use something different than #define-style syntax.  You should look in `stdbase.h` (and any .h included in it) to figure out what TEST/ENDTEST are defined as. (probably some type of macro)

Comment: Yup, I lost my Linux VM so I can only look at this through SVN. But yeh, they're both macros. I wasn't thinking until I saw alk's comment about the literals. I just breezed over the 001 not thinking about it.